# getting an error while changing a record value in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
move :: Board -> Direction -> Board
move board direction = board {selector = (fst (selector board) + fst direction, snd (selector board) + snd direction)}
```

this is what I wrote as code but I get this error message when I try to use "move":

```
<interactive>:91:1: error:
    * No instance for (Show Board) arising from a use of `print'
    * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it`
```

I understand that I can't print "initBoard" but I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You're trying to print a board but there isn't a way to print boards. What's confusing?

Comment: Your function was able to compute a result in your test, but since you are in GHCi, Haskell will also try to _print_ the result. That fails since you code does no define how a `Board` should be printed. Likely, you need to use `data Board = ...... deriving Show` -- the `deriving Show` part tells Haskell to print `Board` in a default format.

Comment: @chi Although a more formal declaration of how to show the board may give better results. A simple default print of the components of the board might look so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GHCi, if you do:

```hs
ghci> board1 = move board0 dir
```

You will be able to use your `move` function without error. But if you evaluate an expression whose type isn't an instance of `Show`, then you get the error:

```hs
ghci> move board0 dir
```

Same goes for any other type, like functions:

```hs
ghci> add1 = (1 +)
ghci> add1 2
3
ghci> add1

<interactive>:5:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```